# Angular sidenav.toggle() doesn't work after button reappear by *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is the exact same code from [Angular material website](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#creating-a-responsive-layout-for-mobile-amp-desktop) showing how to create different `sidenav` for mobile and desktop.

```
<div class="example-container" [class.example-is-mobile]="mobileQuery.matches" *ngIf="shouldRun">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <h1 class="example-app-name">Responsive App</h1>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
                         [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
                 [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <p *ngFor="let content of fillerContent">{{content}}</p>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!shouldRun">Please open on Stackblitz to see result</div>
```

I want the menu button only appear when it is mobile. I add `*ngIf="mobileQuery.matches"` to it.

Change the 3rd line to:

```
<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="mobileQuery.matches" (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

Strangely, if you resize the window to make the button disappear then resize it to make the button appear again, the button won't work anymore. The `sidenav` will not show when you click it. Only when you resize the window again, the menu will suddenly appear.

[You can test it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2q5ru9)

Comment: The StackBlitz link you've posted does not include the changes you've made to the 3rd line.

Comment: @Edric I'm not familiar with StackBlitz, I saved change and press share, don't know why it's not work, maybe you can copy and replace the line to test.

Comment: You're supposed to fork the StackBlitz and then save it.

Comment: If you add some logs, you see that the click event is fired, the problem lies in your media query in the mat-sidenav (line 9)
If you remove it you'll see that your button is working, I'd advise to start from there

Comment: Thanks, I think the link is working now, I'll try change the media query later.

Comment: Ok I'll propose this as an answer then

Comment: @JeffreyChen it's actually a problem with change detection. See my answer with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your main goal is to show/hide the menu button, I think you only need the following code into the constructor:

```
constructor(media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
}
```

Everything works fine after applying that change. Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2q5ru9-qgcbxh).

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: OK this is interesting because his example worked fine as long as you manually trigger change detection (see my answer). But this **also** works. I believe the reason the original Angular Material example was triggering change detection on `this.mobileQuery` is: `sideNav` uses `onPush` change detection.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution. Dean's answer also works and explains more about this problem. But since I'll use this on my project, I'll choose this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange one. It actually is a problem with change detection. If you manually trigger change detection after toggling the sidebar, everything works fine. Consider the following:

```html
<!-- On click, call our toggle function which will toggle the side-nav and 
     trigger change detection -->
<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="mobileQuery.matches" (click)="toggle(snav)"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

And our `toggle` function:

```js
toggle(sidenav: any) {
  sidenav.toggle();
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Everything works as expected. Additionally, if you just show/hide the button (don't remove it from the DOM), everything works as expected:

```html
<!-- As long as you only show/hide the button, everything works as expected -->
<div [hidden]="!mobileQuery.matches">
  <button mat-icon-button  (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
</div>
```

I have [created a stackblitz that shows these examples working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2q5ru9-5q9yrx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html). This is really strange and I think you may have discovered a bug in Angular Material. Let me know if you are going to submit a bug request on the repo; if not, I will.

Comment: I'm a little too busy to submit it right now. Feel free to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After removing changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() the issue was gone.

Answer (score -1):

The click event works fine (you can add some logs to check it), it's actually the media query on the mat-sidenav tag (line 9) that breaks the snav.toggle()